# Alfresco - Search metadata in OpenSearch image does not work

Tags: alfresco, opensearch, acs, alfresco-enterprise

I'm using alfresco entreprise search 23.1.0, alfresco-elasticsearch-live-indexing-mediation and metadata (both 4.0.0.1) and opensearch image 1.3.14 just to indexing the metadata from documents (and not the content).

My search in opensearch does not work when when I stop alfresco and restart it.

To work, I have to delete the opensearch volume and start a new instance of it, then the search works fine. (Because the environnement is clean/new?)

The error that I got:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Map.containsKey(Object)" because **"this.configuration" is null**

at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.elasticsearch.contentmodelsync.IndexConfigurationInitializer.isPropertyIndexed(IndexConfigurationInitializer.java:98) ~[alfresco-enterprise-repository-23.1.0.230.jar:2
3.1.0.230]

It's weird that the NullPointer is thrown in a 'contentmodelsync' package.

In my case, I indexing just the metadata from a document and not it's content.

My alfresco-elasticsearch-live-indexing-mediation image has the 'alfresco.content-indexing-component.enabled=false' property.

The indexing feature works fine, but the search after the restart not.

I already checked the opensearch-volume, I can search my documents via postman even after the restart of all containers.

I have searched for some configuration to disable some sort of a content mode sync, but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

In fact Alfresco has fixed this issue in the version 23.2

https://community.hyland.com/en/Products/alfresco/release-notes/release-notes/alfresco-content-services-232